# Azure VM Snapshot performance issue

Tags: azure, snapshot

Can we create a snapshot when the Azure VM is in running state? By any chance does this operation will impact the VM performance

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a snapshot when the Azure VM is in a running state. However, it's recommended that you cleanly shut down the VM before taking a snapshot, to clear out any processes that are in progress. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/snapshot-copy-managed-disk

For example, you can run the following PowerShell commands to create a snapshot.

```
$resourceGroupName = 'xxx' 
$location = 'xxx' 
$vmName = 'xxx'
$snapshotName = 'xxx'


$vm = Get-AzVM `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Name $vmName


$snapshot =  New-AzSnapshotConfig `
-SourceUri $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id `
-Location $location `
-CreateOption copy


New-AzSnapshot `
    -Snapshot $snapshot `
    -SnapshotName $snapshotName `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
```